# Where to go after academia in the humanities?

Tags: career-path, job-search, europe, humanities, fine-performing-arts

I am a full prof in the humanities at a small liberal arts college in rural America. I am relishing my sabbatical in a European country with a flourishing economy and appealing culture. I do not want to return home. I travel abroad every summer and so do not attribute my thoughts about a major move to reverse culture shock. I mainly want to stay for the benefit of my children where here they can get a better education and have better opportunities.

There are currently no jobs in my field that I have seen advertised in the country where we are living. I have also been putting the word out to my academic contacts here that I want to stay, but so far I haven't heard about any job opportunities.

I'm not certain I could compete for jobs when they come up given that I have devoted my career thus far to teaching and service, and I'm not a newly minted PhD. I have pubs and am doing research, but not on the level of what I'd have had I been at a research institution all these years. While I'm passionate about teaching, I'm far from retirement age and am prepared to make a career change.

How can I channel my training and work experience to something that would be of interest to a European employer (or an employer at a better city in the US to at least get us out of our rural community)?

Comment: This is going to depend a lot on what field you are in, and what your other skills are, I think. I know someone with a PhD in anthropology who now runs a specialized online store... and is glad to finally have found a job that utilizes all of their skills.

Comment: Not-academia is a pretty large and diverse labour market... I don't think there is one strategy that will work for that entire range of jobs. It also depends the country you want to go to.

Comment: Thank you. Both of you have made fair points. I'm holding back details for the sake of anonymity. I'm in a major European city and my field is in the visual arts. I suppose I was hoping for some sources/career coaches/websites that I have tackled this question already. I have also been thinking about the plausibility of a career in online teaching that could be done anywhere. The anthropologist's specialized online store sounds intriguing...

Comment: you can always ask employment agents, but do you have right on it as person on subatical. Getting in humanities with Fine art phd? can you do reaserch? can you publish papers? what is your H index? productivity of reaserch output? visual arts, can you be professor for IT sector? like graphic design ?

Comment: Are you ready to accept a salary decrease? At least in Spain native English speakers are appreciated at high school or freelance teaching, although admittedly the market is starting to saturate.

Comment: @SSimon in the humanities we don't really tend to pay attention to the H-index very much — it's a very sciences-oriented metric.

Comment: Check out resources from theprofessorisin on switching careers (she calls it post-ac)

Comment: It's a myth that your job has to be related to your diplomas. [According to the OCDE](https://www.oecd.org/publications/getting-skills-right-assessing-and-anticipating-changing-skill-needs-9789264252073-en.htm), more than 40% of European workers have a job that do not correspond to their level of education, for example.

Comment: Thank you for these good suggestions. I will look into them. Miguel, yes that is an issue (saturation of Eng speakers). I'm curious to know if there is a real place for someone from the humanities in the tech industry. Dawn, thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Najib, that's an interesting statistic. On a related note, I've noticed much more fluidity in the European job market. It seems more common for people to change jobs and careers more frequently in Europe than in the US. Conversations I've had with friends here have inspired me to reconsider my own career path.

Comment: The USA is part of the OCDE, and the full report include some statistics about the USA. According to Figure 1.3, the "total mismatch" in the USA (qualification + field of study + literacy) is close to 60%, close to the average of the OCDE. You can find more detailed info in the report.

Comment: @guifa well yes, but still if we dont know more about OP we cannot help about europe.

Comment: Since you're in the visual arts, perhaps look into art galleries and museums? Plenty of them in most major European cities...

Comment: Thank you, all. Yes, I'm exploring the possibility of leaving my teaching position to do something entirely different so that my family can leave the US and live abroad. My career thus far has been spent teaching a wide variety of courses in the humanities with a focus on the visual arts. I am a full prof at a SLAC where the focus is teaching and service, not research. I do research, but the bulk of my cv reflects my institution's expectations (heavy course load and committee work). I do not think I can compete for positions in my field at research institutions in this European country.

Comment: Moreover, fluency in the language spoken in this country is a requirement for teaching positions at comparable institutions to my SLAC where the focus is on teaching, not research. So, I think a teaching position for me in this country is out. For that reason, I am open to a major career shift that repackages my skills for something outside academe. I have encountered countless blogs, books, websites, and lists of career consultants ready to charge me a great deal of money to coach me as I make the change ("post-ac").

Comment: Before I plunk down this money, I'm turning to this community to start a conversation about my options. I'm interested in reading "real-life" experiences of others who have done something similar or practical tips in helping me move forward. I'm also entertaining the idea of rebranding myself as an online instructor for US institutions and doing that full time in Europe (is that possible?). Of course, I imagine there are many others who are contemplating a move out of academia and so the comments here may be useful to them, too. Thanks so much, again.

Comment: What about positions teaching American Studies or related subjects? Even if you haven't focused on humanities in the U.S., would you be willing to teach something comparative if that was easier to find a job? (This is on the assumption that language fluency requirements might be waived for those roles.) I do bet that you could remotely be an online instructor. Two other possibilities that take advantage of your unique position and skills would be to coordinate study abroad opportunities or English-language tours (think a humanities-infused Rick Steves, perhaps?). Good luck!